# Sql query Order by giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
"select top 5 db_statesid 
   from seo_states 
   where db_statesid in (" +
            "SELECT TOP 5 db_statesid 
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.db_statesid 
                       FROM seo_states a 
                      where country_id=" + country_id + ") 
              ORDER BY RND(db_statesid))";
```

I'm using this query for access and it works fine but not for sql giving syntax error near Order by.

Comment: Is `RND` a round or random function in Access? What is the ***FULL*** error you're receiving?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: You cannot include ORDER BY in a sub query. Try removing the ORDER BY and it will work smoothly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql all derived tables must be aliased. Note the addition of `t1` before `ORDER BY`

```
"select top 5 db_statesid 
   from seo_states 
   where db_statesid in (" +
            "SELECT TOP 5 db_statesid 
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.db_statesid 
                       FROM seo_states a 
                      where country_id=" + country_id + ") t1
              ORDER BY RND(db_statesid))"
```

**Edit**

Unless `RND` is a custom function, you probably want `RAND`

Comment: `RND` is not a valid function in SQL Server